WordPress Ошибка установки соединения с базой данных?
wordpress у меня работает с openserver и в качестве субд mysql
В wordpress я новичок и мне пришла задача что я должен доработать сайт написанный на wordpress, мне дали ftp данные и я с сервера перенес себе wp данные сайта (в папку которую я создал в openserver domains). И когда я запускаю сервер и выбираю проект у меня вылезает ошибка: Ошибка установки соединения с базой данных. Я не понимаю почему она появляется и как ее исправить? я пробовал создать бд в mysql на своем пк с данными из wp-config.php но так же проблема не решилась.
Что мне делать с этой ошибкой?



Во первых не используй виновые недосервера. Во вторых ты уже всё поломал.  Изучай. В третьих учи ВП в принципе, а заказ отдай тому кто понимает в ВП.
